# Trying to put three divs on the same line, one against the other, centered, on IE6, IE7, IE8 and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html

I have a problem doing this :

--space--  div1_left div2_center div3_right  --space--

Div 1 and 3 contain an image and Div 2 contains a ul/li based css dropdown menu.
Div 1 and 3 are sticked against div 2.
The total line is centered horizontally.

I am able to achieve this on Firefox and IE8 without problem.
But on IE7 and IE6 this doesn't work.
I need it to be compatible on all IE >= 6 and Firefox browsers.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You could perhaps show some of your css, how you do that

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Change your current 'div' elements to 'span' elements. They will by default be inline and render side by side.
2. Wrap this content in a 'div' with an id of 'nav'.
3. Set the CSS style of the 'nav' element to include a 'margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;' styles. This will center the whole thing on the page.
4. Be sure you are using a CSS reset to help normalize the rendering across browsers.

Hope this helps.

Bob

UPDATE: Here is a link to an example:

http://jsbin.com/onasi/3/edit

Answer (score 2):

Well I would make 1 container `div` with left and right padding and margins left and right: auto.

and inside of it 3 `div`'s with this style:

```
width:100px;/* or how much you want (the sum of all must be <= container width) */
float:left;
```

Answer (score 1):

To be precise on the basis of answer given by rcravens here's the code:

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; height: 50px; position: relative;
background-image: none; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px" class='ui-state-default'>
        <span style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 33%;height: 100%;">
                <img id="imgLeft" style="float: left; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"class='logo' src='' alt='' />
       </span>
       <span style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 33%;">
                <input type="text" id="txtSearch" style="width: 50%" />
                 <img id="btnGlobalSearch" class="findImage" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle" src="<%= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/"%>Images/icons/find.png" />
       </span>
       <span style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 33%;height: 100%;">
               <img id="imgRight" style="float: right; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"  src='' class='logo' alt='' />
       </span>
</div>
```

this satisfies the cravings of IE7 .....